# Dynamic column value to be set as next row's another column value in Oracle

Tags: oracle, dynamic

I am new to Oracle and I would like to form an Oracle query:

```
Id     CrLmt    Type    Unit    Price   Amount  Prev_bal    NewBal
5-00001 100000  Sell    100      150    15000   100000       85000
                Buy      75      600    45000   85000       130000
                Buy      85      550    46750   130000      176750
                Sell     60     1000    60000   176750      116750
5-00002 90000   Sell    100      400    40000   90000        50000
                Buy     550      300    165000  50000       215000
                Sell    300     1000    300000  215000      -85000
```

My conditions are as follows:

1. ID and CrLmt are combination and its subsequent rows come under this ID, CrLmt combination.
2. For every ID, CrLmt combination, the CrLmt will be assigned in Prev_Bal column, rest of the rows will have a calculation
3. Based on Buy/Sell in Type column, the values in Amount and Prev_Bal will be added or subtracted and the resultant value should be displayed in NewBal (dynamic) column
4. If the Type is "Sell" then the value in PrevBal should be subtracted with Amount column value and if the Type is "Buy" then then the value in PrevBal should be added with Amount column value and the resultant value should be displayed in NewBal (dynamic) column in the corresponding row
5. The value obtained in NewBal column in row 1 should be displayed in row 2 Prev_Bal column for 2nd row's calculation and so on.
6. If any negative value occurs in NewBal column the same needs to be carried out to next calculations.

I tried using LAG function to get previous values but doesn't know how to get a dynamic column's (NewBal) values on the go.

Comment: can you format your data?

Comment: JRG, is it better now??

Comment: Is everything in one table only ? Or do you have a table with your credit limit and one with the transactions which refers to the credit limit table ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: This is a good statement of requirements, but I think it is too broad for Stack Overflow. There is a view amongst regular readers that we should encourage posters to make a solid attempt to solve their problem, rather than bringing it to us in the first instance. If significant effort or research has already been made, please edit that in - including any unfinished queries - otherwise please do try this yourself.

Comment: @halfer, apologize for the word "urgency" being mentioned in my question and I missed to give a detailed info of my requirement. Let me rephrase my question and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little example that you will have to adapt to your current structure. You will need a date on your transaction for the order clause of the sum.

all you need is a running sum to which you will either add the credit limit for the new_balance or to which you will take the previous row for the old_balance

```
--TEST DATA
CREATE TABLE credit_limit ( id varchar2(10), crlmt number );
CREATE TABLE transactions (transaction_type varchar2(4), unit number, price number, amount number, crlmt_id varchar2(10), date_transaction date );
INSERT INTO credit_limit values ('5-00001',100000);
INSERT INTO credit_limit values ('5-00002',90000);
INSERT INTO transactions values ('Sell',100,150,15000,'5-00001',sysdate-4);
INSERT INTO transactions values ('Buy',75,600,45000,'5-00001',sysdate-3);
INSERT INTO transactions values ('Buy',85,550,46750,'5-00001',sysdate-2);
INSERT INTO transactions values ('Sell',60,1000,60000,'5-00001',sysdate-1);

INSERT INTO transactions values ('Sell',100,400,40000,'5-00002',sysdate-3);
INSERT INTO transactions values ('Buy',550,300,165000,'5-00002',sysdate-2);
INSERT INTO transactions values ('Sell',300,1000,300000,'5-00002',sysdate-1);

--The query
select cr.id, cr.crlmt, tr.transaction_type, tr.unit, tr.price, tr.amount,
NVL(cr.crlmt + SUM(tr.amount*decode(tr.transaction_type,'Sell',-1,'Buy',1)) 
               OVER (partition by cr.id order by cr.id, tr.date_transaction 
               rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding ),Cr.crlmt) old_bal,
    cr.crlmt + SUM(tr.amount*decode(tr.transaction_type,'Sell',-1,'Buy',1)) 
               OVER (partition by cr.id order by cr.id, tr.date_transaction 
               rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) new_bal
from 
credit_limit cr
JOIN
transactions tr
ON cr.id=tr.crlmt_id
order by cr.id, tr.date_transaction
```

result :

```
ID      CRLMT   TRAN    UNI PRICE   AMOUNT  OLD_BAL NEW_BAL
5-00001 100000  Sell    100 150     15000   100000  85000
5-00001 100000  Buy     75  600     45000   85000   130000
5-00001 100000  Buy     85  550     46750   130000  176750
5-00001 100000  Sell    60  1000    60000   176750  116750
5-00002 90000   Sell    100 400     40000   90000   50000
5-00002 90000   Buy     550 300     165000  50000   215000
5-00002 90000   Sell    300 1000    300000  215000  -85000
```